Can we interpret indefinite integrals as limit of sums like definite integrals? If not, how does solving separable differential equations make sense?
To illustrate my point, let's consider an example: the amount of a radioactive substance is a function of time, $Q(t)$. At the beginning, $t = 0$, and the initial amount of the radioactive substance is $Q(0) = Q_0$. The substance decays at a rate
\begin{equation}
\frac{dQ}{dt} = -kQ
\end{equation},
where $k$ is a positive constant depending on the property of the radioactive substance.
Method 1:
To solve this differential equation, I seperate the variables:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{Q}dQ = -kdt
\end{equation}
This equation may seem wierd but what it really means is the following: If I divide the time from $0$ to $t$ into $N$ subintervals with each subinterval $\delta t = t/N$. Then I can denote the $n$th time interval as $t_n - t_{n-1}$, where $t_n = n \delta t$. Then in each interval my change in Q, $\delta Q$ can be written as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{Q_{n-1}} \delta Q \approx -k \delta t
\end{equation}
with $Q_{n-1} = Q(t_{n-1})$ (i.e. $Q$ is evaluated at the beginning of this interval) and $\delta Q = Q_{n} - Q_{n-1}$. Note as $N \rightarrow \infty$, the above equation is just $\frac{1}{Q}dQ = -kdt$. Then I can add all $N$ intervals together:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{Q_{n-1}} \delta Q \approx \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} -k \delta t
\end{equation}.
Then in the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$, the above sums are the definition of an definite integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{Q' = Q_0}^{Q' = Q(t)} \frac{1}{Q'} dQ' = \int_{t' = 0}^{t' = t} -kdt'
\end{equation}
where $Q'$ and $t'$ are dummy variables to avoid confusion. After the integration and reaarangements, we can obtain the result:
\begin{equation}
Q(t) = Q_0 e^{-kt}
\end{equation}
Method 2:
However, in the above integration, we have implicitly imposed the inition conditions already by writing down the upper and lower limits in the definite integrals.
However, alternatively, what one can also do is write $\frac{1}{Q}dQ = -kdt$ and then just 'integrate both sides':
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{Q}dQ = \int -kdt
\end{equation}
Then one can get $Q(t) = A e^{-kt}$, with $A$ being a random constant depending on the initial condition. And if we impose the initial condition, we end up with the same reuslt $Q(t) = Q_0 e^{-kt}$.
Here is my question:
I think method 2 is a standard way of solving seperable differential equations: you do indefinite integral first and impose inition condition to find the random constant resulting from the indefinite integral. But what an indefinite integral truely is is just the antiderivate of a funtion, and in fact, unlike definite integrals which are defined as limits of a sum, how an indefinite integral $\int f(x) dx$ is defined is: finding the antiderivative of $f(x)$, which has nothing to do with summation (I am not talking about part 2 of the fundamental theorem of calculus which relates the indefinite and definite integrals.) So in method 2, I am just finding the antideratives of the two functions. Method 1 is perfectly clear to me as the limit of summation. However, in method 2, indicated by $\frac{1}{Q}dQ = -kdt$, which are limit of $\frac{1}{Q} \delta Q \approx -k \delta t$ as $\delta t \rightarrow \infty$, I think what we are really doing is also a summation similar to that in method 1, but this disagrees with the antiderivative interpretation of an indefinite integral. So, I want to ask: how can we interpret the indefinite integral as a summation? If so, how? If not, without the summation in mind, how does method 2 make sense?
Or maybe, an reinterpretation of $\frac{1}{Q}dQ = -kdt$ would help?
Hope my question is clear. Let me know if there is any confusion.


Can we interpret indefinite integrals as limit of sums like definite integrals?

In general, no; the indefinite integral is defined only as the inverse of a derivative. However, there is a result that
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt=f(x),
$$
which links the definite integral to a indefinite integral. (There is no guarantee, however, that every anti-derivative of $f$ can be obtained by choosing some value of $a$.)

Without the summation in mind, how does method 2 make sense?

The standard explanation of "separation of variables" can be misleading. Here’s a clearer interpretation:
When solving a first-order ODE, if the equation can be written as
$$
\mathrm{d}f(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \,\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \,\mathrm{d}y = 0,
$$
then the solution is obvious:
$$
f(x, y) = C,
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. For ODEs of the form
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \varphi(x) \psi(y),
$$
we can transform it into
$$
\varphi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x - \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\psi(y)} = 0,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\mathrm df(x,y)=0,\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = {\varphi(x)}, \\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -\frac{1}{\psi(y)},\\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}= 0.
$$
Let
$$
u(x) = \int {\varphi(x)} \,\mathrm{d}x, \quad v(y) = \int \frac{1}{\psi(y)} \,\mathrm{d}y,
$$
then the solution is
$$
f(x, y) = u(x) - v(y) = C,
$$
which is the same as the one given by the separation of variables method.
